# How to use FIND_IN_SET() query in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, function, codeigniter

I have two tables- One with attendance details and another one with student detail. The following are the table structures:

### tbl_attendance

aid             date                     attendance

1           2017-03-09            5,6,9             
 2            2017-04-06          12,6,10

### tbl_students

student_id          name

5                               John
6                   Bryan

9                   Anna

10                 Mathew

12                 Susan

Now, I want to display the names of the absentees in the view  as something like say. for example:

Date                 Absentees

2017-03-09   John, Bryan, Anna

2017-03-06   Susan, Bryan, Mathew

I was trying to do it with FIND_IN_SET()..but it seems bad luck..Is there a better way to sort this out?

### UPDATE

I used this query instead and it echoed only the first id's name in each row...

```
    $query = $this->db
   ->select("tbl_attendance.*,tbl_students.name")
   ->from("tbl_attendance")
   ->join("tbl_students","tbl_students.student_id=tbl_attendance.attendance")
   ->where('FIND_IN_SET(tbl_students.student_id, tbl_attendance.attendance)')
   ->GROUP_BY('tbl_students.student_id')
   ->get()->result_array();
```

But as there are three numbers separated by commas in each row I want the rest to be echoed as well.

Answer (score 5):

**This Works**

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select("td.Date, GROUP_CONCAT(ts.student_name SEPARATOR ',')")
    ->from("tbl_students AS ts")
    ->join("tbl_attendance AS ta","find_in_set(ts.st_id,ta.attendance)<> 0","left",false)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

How about that ?

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select("td.Date, GROUP_CONCAT(ts.student_name)")
    ->from("tbl_students AS ts")
    ->join("tbl_attendance AS ta","find_in_set(ts.st_id,ta.attendance)","left",false)
    ->get();
```

Comment: It shows MYSQL Syntax error..bad luck for me... :-(

Comment: oh my bad - i updated my answer - the left as 3rd parameter was missing

Comment: This is the error I Get: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(ts.st_id,ta.attendance))' at line 3

Comment: yeah - i updated my answer because i left out the 3rd parameter - try it again

Comment: Query returned this error -> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ts.st_id,ta.attendance)

Answer (score 0):

You can try query like this,

```
SELECT a.`date`,group_concat(s.student_name)  
FROM tbl_attendance a,tbl_students s  
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(s.st_id, a.attendance) group by `date`;
```

Description :
`FIND_IN_SET` that allows you to find the position of a string within a comma-separated list of strings.

Syntax:

```
FIND_IN_SET(needle,haystack);
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Actually I want to echo all the dates and its corresponding absentees list. Above shown is just an example...

Comment: I var_dumped the result of the above query and it echoed the result with repeating names for so many times like this "Achu,Achu,Achu,Achu,Achu,Achu,Achu,Achu,Achu,Achu,Achu,sruthy,sruthy,sruthy,sruthy,sruthy,sruthy,sruthy,sruthy,sruthy,sruthy,sruthy,sruthy,sruthy,

Comment: I made some changes please try again

Comment: I wanted the query to use in codeigniter ...when I tried this query in the codeigniter form, I am getting syntax errors...so could you please help me in that aspect as well...

Answer (score 0):

Here comma separated category IDs are saved in row 'category' eg., '12,15,7,19'

```
$category_ID = 15;
```

`$this->db->select('*');
 $this->db->from('products');
 $this->db->where('FIND_IN_SET("'.$category_ID.'","category") <>','0');
 $this->db->where('deleted','0');
 $this->db->order_by('product_ID', 'DESC');`

I hope this helps CI developers to use **FIND_IN_SET**.